# How to convert an an opencv image using cvBridge?

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I convert  an image I have opened through opencv into sensor_msgs/image??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32880/how-to-convert-an-an-opencv-image-using-cvbridge??/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-30**:
If either of these answers answered your question, please mark one as "correct" so this questions gets closed out ... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend the [cv_bridge tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a snippet of code I have used to do this and the full code is [here](https://github.com/walchko/camera_node). It is a package that also uses opencv to grab images and publish them. Some of the variables are:

```
image_transport::ImageTransport transport;
image_transport::CameraPublisher image_pub;
camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager info_mgr;
```

And the code:

```
        // if subscribers, pub images
        if(image_pub.getNumSubscribers() >  0) {

            ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();

            // convert OpenCV image to ROS message
            cv_bridge::CvImage cvi;
            cvi.header.stamp = time;
            cvi.header.frame_id = "image";
            cvi.encoding = "bgr8";
            cvi.image = cv_image;

            // get camera parameters 
            sensor_msgs::CameraInfo info = info_mgr.getCameraInfo();
            info.header.stamp = cvi.header.stamp;
            info.header.frame_id = cvi.header.frame_id; // whatever it is called
            info.width = cv_image.cols;
            info.height = cv_image.rows;

            sensor_msgs::Image im;
            cvi.toImageMsg(im);
            image_pub.publish(im,info);
        }
```

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3